# How to send text to a particular whatsapp user from my app?

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I want to send a text message ("e.g. Hello World") to a particular whatsapp user from my app.

Base on this [whatsapp FAQ link](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013), I can just use the custom URL scheme to launch whatsapp to a particular contact number with a predefine text:

**Question:**

**1) But where to get the contact ID, abid?:**

**2) How do I know if the contact number has whatsapp in the first place [for iOS we can't access it because of sandbox limitation right?] ?**

**3) How to insert the contact ID into the URL:**

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can `UIactivityViewController` instead, so apps that support your text will appear:

```
NSString * text = @"Hello World!!";
NSArray * itemsArray = @[text];
NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;

UIActivityViewController * activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                 UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                 // Whatever you want prevent to appear...
                                                 ];

activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You are also able to add images, etc.